# Why Spring Web Flux dispatch handler to bounded elastic schedule

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I find that the thread runs my custom code is named as [boundedElastic-1]. I know that spring web flux use netty, and I find reactor-epoll thread which is similar to NettyEventLoop. I think that my no-blocking custom code should run in reactor-epoll thread pool, but it is not. Is there something I can configure for that?

Comment: spring web flux version is 2.2.2

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a feature in [WebFlux](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1089).

According to the the [comment](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1089#issuecomment-628156957) and [git blame](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/70a3dbff24e7e39b8be9861a6fcb0cd05eb52bb2), `WebSession` will be created in `Schedulers.parallel()` since Spring 5.2.2 or Spring Boot 2.2.2.

So, it's a feature, not a bug.